# JMS Queue Not Appearing in JMS Adapter

Tags: oracle11g, queue, jms, soa, bpel

I have just started working with Oracle SOA Suite 11g. I have created a new JMS Queue in "Enterprise Console". I have created new "ConnectionFactory and Queue" and deployed them. However, in SOA Composite in JDeveloper, when I try to browse it through "JMS Adapter", it does not appear in "JMS Adapter". Can anyone please help me what I am missing here?

Comment: Hello

Is the server up?
Did you released the configurations on weblogic console?

Comment: Hello, Yes, server was up. However, I solved the issue by following some other tutorial. Still did not figure out what was the actual cause :) Thanks